# Clear the extent GUI element created by QgsMapToolExtent prior to QGIS 3.20

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Since QGIS 3.20 the [`QgsMapToolExtent`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.20/gui/QgsMapToolExtent.html) class has a [`clearRubberBand`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.20/gui/QgsMapToolExtent.html#qgis.gui.QgsMapToolExtent.clearRubberBand) method.

For versions of QGIS prior to 3.20, it appears that the element created by `QgsMapToolExtent` is not a `QgsRubberBand`, but rather a `QGraphicsItem`.

What is a safe/robust way of clearing the extent element off the map canvas, without unsetting the map tool?

The following snippet instantiates the map tool and sets it to the map canvas. Dragging a rectangle on the canvas leaves the extent object that I want to clear.

```py
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
t = QgsMapToolExtent(canvas)
canvas.setMapTool(t)
```

The object appears in the list of `iface.mapCanvas().scene().items()` but I don't know how to properly identify it. It is not necessarily the last element in the list, and it is not assigned an `objectName()` or a `toolTip()`.

```py
items = [x for x in canvas.scene().items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `deactivate()` clears the extent GUI element without unsetting the tool.

```py
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
t = QgsMapToolExtent(canvas)
canvas.setMapTool(t)

# after dragging an extent:
t.deactivate()
```